# Dispatch (useReducer) function not working when passing it as props (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

1. When user clicks a button, I want to show a component for 2s.
2. After the 2s, I want to run a function(s) that are coming from props. But, the `dispatch` function is not working.

Any idea how can I fix it?

```
const Expire = (props: any) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setVisible(false);
    }, props.delay);
  }, [props.delay]);

  if (visible) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // PROBLEM HERE
      props.trigger();
    }, props.delay);
  }
  return visible ? <div>{props.children}</div> : <div />;
};
```

```
 <Expire
          trigger={() => {
          // PROBLEM HERE. The dispatch function is not being executed.
            dispatch({
              type: COMPLETION_POPUP
            });
            console.log("run this function too");
          }}
          delay="2000"
        >
          Popup Animation
        </Expire>
```

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-leavitt-ou7weu?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

1. Setting setTimeout in body of component. Move it to useEffect.
2. Passing delay="2000" as a string. It should be delay={2000}

I fixed with:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setVisible(false);
    }, props.delay);
  }, [props.delay]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!visible) {
      props.trigger();
    }
  }, [visible]);
```

Note: Huge thanks to EvokeMe from Reactiflux.